# This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString must contain..Xcode Sticker app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect

Can you help me to fix this error? I'm try to send a new release of my sticker application from Xcode to iTunes connect, but I don't find how to change `CFBundleShortVersionString`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your plist file and change the version for line `Bundle versions string, short`. You can't upload your app to itunes connect with the same version multiple times.

Comment: It does not work the same

Comment: be more specific please

Comment: I changed in my plist.file the line you told me with the version 1.1 but Xcode gives me the same error

Comment: if you already released your app you have to create a new version on itunes connect, maybe this is the issue. Also you can change your build version (there are 2 entries for version) in your plist